# How often should I check on Foxy?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys

I've been playing FNAF recently and I have a pretty good thing going where I only check the lights and on Foxy. But I can't seem to nail the timing with Foxy.

On the wiki it says "depending on how often the player checks him he will emerge from Pirate Cove faster or slower. If the player checks too often or too little he will emerge faster"

How frequently should I check on Foxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're playing FNAF 1. In that case, you need to check on him ***really*** often if you're playing 4-20 mode, but not keep the monitor up for that long. That's what the wiki means. This might come as a surprise, but you don't need to check on foxy's camera in particular, you just need to check a *camera*. So you can look at cam 2, and it will count as checking on him. That allows you to cam stall Freddy on cam 2.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what night you're on, as the chance he moves each cycle becomes larger. You do not have to check Foxy's camera, any camera will do, but it is nice to see where he is at every once in a while. There is no such thing as checking on him too often, (this rumour probably spread from phone guy or a lets player) but be sure that you check on him quite a bit depending on the difficulty settings. If you have something set up to tell you when each cycle happens, that may make things easier for you, as while the game has a lot of rng related features, each cycle takes around 3-4 seconds.